# Pass function parameter to then in Javascript

Tags: javascript

By default methodB takes `text` parameter. How do I pass `title` parameter as additional parameter from methodA to methodB ?

```
function methodA(link,title){
    return superagent.get(link).then(page => page.text).then(methodB); <== here
}

function methodB(text,title) {
    const promotions = [];
    const html = cheerio.load(text);

    html("#promolain > li > a > img").each((index, element) => {
        //console.log("scraping promo : "+element.attribs.title);
        promotions.push(element.attribs);
    });

    return promotions;
}
```

Comment: In `.then(methodB)`, use an anonymous function instead of `methodB`. I.e., `.then(function(resp) { methodB(resp.text,resptitle); })` or `.then(resp => methodB(resp.text,resp.title);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a fat arrow function:

```
function methodA(link,title){
    return superagent.get(link)
        .then(page => page.text)
        .then(text => methodB(text, title));
}
```